# How to retain form values while navigating between different jsp in a struts application

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I am developing a `struts2` application , which includes user to input multiple data on different page.

For different page, i am using different `JSP` and for capturing data from each page, i have one `formbean` class. 
I can see values are getting set in setters in `formbean` class when i navigate to another page. however, if enter data on `page 1` , go to `page 2` and again come back to `page 1`, the entered values are lost.

How to store values while navigating between different page. Number of fields on my page are many.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Store them somewhere (e.g. session). You can use some plugin (e.g [ActionFlow](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-actionflow)).

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr... how to store it in a session. If my formbean object 'HouseHoldInfo' contains all the information for page 1, how can i save it in session and retrieve again.

Comment: `session#put` and `session#get`.